# How to set a integer value as the title of navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar

Essentially I would like to set the value of a variable as the title shown in the navigation controller. The variable is called `titleAmount` and should represent the number of rows in a table view.

To do this I created the variable `var titleAmount:String?`

and in `numberOfRowsInSection` I added the following:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let theIntegerValue :Int = feedItems.count
        let theStringValue :String = String(theIntegerValue)
        titleAmount = theStringValue
        return feedItems.count

    }
```

Because the title must be a string and my variable is looking for a string, I added the following above:

```
let theIntegerValue :Int = feedItems.count
let theStringValue :String = String(theIntegerValue)
```

To convert the value of `feedItems.count` into a string

> **^^ This is probably where the issue is ^^**

The `feedItems.count` displays the number of rows in my tableview. (I have tested and confirmed it works)

Lastly in `viewDidLoad()` I added **self.navigationItem.title = titleAmount** to set the value of the variable as the navigation bar title.

Nothing shows up the field is left blank. What is the issue?

Comment: Try putting a break point or print titleAmount in your viewDidLoad. I am thinking you are assigning that variable before the data is there. You need to update it after the data is loaded/reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be attempting to update the title in `numberOfRowsInSection`. Update the title wherever you populate or update `feedItems`.

Anywhere you update the number of items in `feedItems` you need to update title:

```
self.navigationItem.title = "\(feedItems.count)"
```

And keep in mind that even though you did `self.navigationItem.title = titleAmount` in `viewDidLoad`, any further changes to `titleAmount` are not going to be reflected in the title.

Comment: Nice. You could also use a didSet on feedItems.

Comment: @GntlmnBndt Yes, that is also a good way to ensure the title is kept up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

numberOfRowsInSection is going to execute *after* viewDidLoad. If you are setting titleAmount in numberOfRowsInSection, titleAmount will have been nil when you went to access it earlier.

If you can observe feedItems and update the title when they change that should address your issue. As of right now, I think you're having an order of operations issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var feeditems: [FeedItem] = [FeedItem]() {
    didSet {
        self.navigationItem.title = "Available items: \(feedItems.count)"
        reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return feedItems.count
}
```

This is a stripped down version but should very easily be implemented for your usecase. Make sure the feedItems is set properly.

Comment: Where should the var be written?

Comment: somewhere in the class.. ideally right on the top of the viewcontroller